# Can you switch your terminal user as any user defined in /etc/passwd?

Tags: server, bash, permissions

**Context**

This is very newbie question but I dont fully grasp *unix* users yet.

If I `cat /etc/passwd` there are different users:

```
me:x:1000:1000:me,,,:/home/me:/bin/bash
systemd-coredump:x:999:999:systemd Core Dumper:/:/usr/sbin/nologin
sddm:x:127:134:Simple Desktop Display Manager:/var/lib/sddm:/bin/false
mongodb:x:128:65534::/home/mongodb:/usr/sbin/nologin
sshd:x:129:65534::/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
tftp:x:130:138:tftp daemon,,,:/srv/tftp:/usr/sbin/nologin
_rpc:x:131:65534::/run/rpcbind:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

most of them are no login users (so we would say you can't log in unless it is a /bash user), but if I try this command:

```
su - mongodb
```

it prompts me for a password. Problem is I don't know the password in this case.

**Question**

- but does this mean I could switch to this user in the terminal and maybe run the process as systemd-service would do?
- so we would say you can't log in unless it is a /bash user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer:

- yes
- yes

If you are the super user (id=0) or commonly known as root, you cannot login in to it if shell is set to /usr/sbin/nologin or /usr/bin/false

as per the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/nologin.8.html#:%7E:text=nologin%20displays%20a%20message%20that,instead%20of%20the%20default%20message.) description of nologin:

```
   **DESCRIPTION**
   nologin displays a message that an account is not available and
   exits non-zero. It is intended as a replacement shell field to
   deny login access to an account.

   If the file /etc/nologin.txt exists, nologin displays its
   contents to the user instead of the default message.

   The exit status returned by nologin is always 1.
```

but (always if you are root or can sudo commands) you can execute a bash as per one user which is noloign user, to impersonate him for troubleshooting

sudo:

```
sudo -u mongodb /bin/bash
```

root:

```
su -s /bin/bash mongodb
```

Those above command does not execute a login, but just execute a bash with the user permission, in this case as mongodb user.

**NOTE:** normally thos user are passwordless, that mean even the ***su -*** process ask you for a password that will never match with nothing also empty password.

Comment: yes @steeldriver, my bad! I correct it

Comment: cant thank enough